# How can I copy the quality (illumination, contrast, brightness, etc) from one picture to another on OPENCV?

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory, face-recognition

I have two images and I want to use the 2nd image as a basis to edit the quality of the 1st image.

How can I do this on openCV?

[image: 1st Image]

[image: 2nd Image]

Comment: see https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/

Comment: Thanks man! This solves it!! I just have to change the way it its being converted since I'm using google colab. Instead of running the code on terminal, I passed in the return data to cv2.imshow. `cv2.imshow(color_transfer(source, target))`